# Generating $S_7$ only by $7$-cycles

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

Do all the $7$-cycles in $S_7$ generate $S_7$? How?

Can we generalize the idea?

---

(Edited)

I found a new idea:

Assume $$\sigma = (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7)$$ and $$\tau=(x_7,x_6,x_5,x_4,x_3,x_1,x_2)$$ Now: $$\sigma\tau=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$$
So, we can generate all $3$-cycles.

**Theorem**: Let $n ≥ 3$. Prove that $A_n$ can be generated by all the $3$-cycles in $S_n$.

What should I do for $S_n - A_n$?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Hint: can you figure out how to use two seven-cycles to make a two-cycle? Try 'drawing out' a cycle as a circle of arrows and see if you can build another cycle of arrows that will bring almost all the elements back to their original place.

Comment: You are mixing up $A_n$ and $S_n$ it seems. $A_n$ is much smaller

Comment: Yes. Sorry, you are right.  @Vincent

Comment: One generalization of the result you quote is that the set of all $m$-cycles generates $A_n$ for odd $m$; the proof is not so different from the $m = 3$ case. The bad news is that it does not generate anything else - for reasons TheSilverDoe mentions

Comment: +1 for showing how to get 3-cycles. Unfortunately it ends there.

Answer (score 4):

No. A $7-$cycle has parity $+1$, therefore you cannot reach a transposition just using $7-$cycles.

Comment: Thank you, Can you prove this formally please?

Comment: Do you know what is the parity of a permutation ? If so, the argument is formal enough... If no, see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation

Comment: Thank you. I know what is the parity of a permutation, but I can't understand the connection between parity and transposition.

Comment: A transposition has parity $-1$. By composing $7-$cycles, you can only obtain permutation with parity $+1$.

Comment: Are there any other ways to prove? It seems somehow complicated.

Comment: @SepehrOmidvar This is not really complicated, actually... When you learn a little bit more about the structure of the symmetric group, you will see that this is a very natural and straightforward argument.

Comment: Also, why do you find a one-liner complicated? It may be surprising if you haven't seen it before. But a suprise 1-liner should bring joy, shouldn't it? A simple way of proving something initially non-obvious.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I am new to abstract algebra. I started to learn it in the below book and the writer didn't mention anything about parity ... https://www.amazon.com/Algebra-Action-Course-Applied-Undergraduate/dp/1470428490

Comment: @SepehrOmidvar Yes, of course, I understand that for a "beginner", this may seem a little bit abstract. However, just think about the following question : "is it possible to reach any integer of $\mathbb{Z}$ just making sums, substractions, and multiplications of multiples of $4$ ?". Of course, you will answer : "it is impossible, because we can only reach even numbers". Well, this is the exact same here. So don't worry if this seems abstract for the moment, it will be far clearer, when you are more comfortable with the symmetric group !

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. If I found another way to solve this problem, I'll keep you posted. THANKS again.